# What would be the worst case wait in seconds

Tags: networking

What would be the worst case wait in seconds, if a NIC enters exponential back off after 8 collisions? Give your answer in seconds and not bit times taking into consideration that the Ethernet speed is 10 Gbps.

1 bit time =  .1 nanoseconds

Worst Case Wait time =  ? microseconds

I can not seem to figure out this problem

Comment: That's the most unhelpful comment i've ever seen, what does worst case wait time mean? and what is the arithmetic to solve it.

Comment: if using csma/cd the worst backoff time per collision is 2**(n-1), do that for all the collisions (2**(n))-1, multiply by the "bit time" * 512 and then convert to microseconds